# Reddit JsonP Request not returning with callback

Tags: jsonp, reddit

I am trying to make jsonp request to the `subreddits_by_topic` on reddit [api](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_deleteflair). However, it doesn't appear to be returning my request in `callback`. Example request:

http://www.reddit.com/api/subreddits_by_topic.json?query=banana&page=1&start=0&limit=25&jsonp=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1

returning:

```
[{"name": "banana"}, {"name": "trees"}, {"name": "Fitness"},...
```

However another similar request to Reddit is coming back with callback correctly?

http://www.reddit.com/.json?count=25&after=&page=1&start=0&limit=25&jsonp=Ext.data.JsonP.callback2

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback2({"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "", "children": [{"kind": "t3", "data": {"domain": "i.i...
```

I checked the api but couldn't find any supporting documentation.  Is there a different way to specify `callback` on reddit or is it not supported?

Comment: It seems like [you're not the only one](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1kmfqe/reddit_api_not_returning_proper_jsonp/) with this issue.

Comment: @TrevorSenior hrmm, i guess i may have to proxy this request through my server.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's seems like a bug / their API isn't consistent. For example http://www.reddit.com/user/trevorsenior/about.json?jsonp=foo works just fine.

Comment: @TrevorSenior I submitted an issue on the related [github project](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/issues/951)